# How do I search an ActiveX/COM object for a method?

Tags: dll, scripting, activex, tlbinf32

I have an ActiveX/COM DLL. It contains many methods and properties. I would like to be able to ask it if it has a particular symbol, as per the following snippet:

```
If HasMethod( "StdLib.DLL", "ReadFileE" ) Then
    ...
End If
```

Is there a way to do this from, say, VBScript or JScript? If not, where do I go to get the information I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Googling around not quite finding what I wanted, I remembered the [Edanmo](http://www.mvps.org/emorcillo/en/code/vb6/index.shtml) site which got me thinking about TLBINF32.DLL, downloading Microsoft's [TLBINF32.CHM](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224331) and reading up on GetMembersWithSubStringEx. Below is the implementation of it (done in VB6 with a reference to TLBINF32.DLL), some demo VBScript and output, and the wrapping of that functionality in some VBA.

```
Public Function SearchTLIMethodsAndProperties(sTypelib As Variant, sSymbol As Variant) As Variant
    Dim SI As SearchItem
    Dim aResults As Variant
    Dim bFound as boolean
    Dim Groups(1) As InvokeKinds
    Groups(0) = INVOKE_FUNC Or INVOKE_PROPERTYGET Or _
        INVOKE_PROPERTYPUT Or INVOKE_PROPERTYPUTREF

    ReDim aResults(0)
    bFound = False
    With TypeLibInfoFromFile(sTypelib)
    .SearchDefault = tliStClasses Or tliStEvents
    For Each SI In .GetMembersWithSubStringEx(sSymbol, Groups)
        bFound = True
        arr.AAdd_PostIncrement aResults, SI.Name
    Next
    End With
    if bFound then 
    ReDim Preserve aResults(UBound(aResults) - 1)
    end if
    SearchTLIMethodsAndProperties = aResults
End Function
```

VBScript demo. The above code was included in my StdLib DLL in the Registry coclass.

```
Dim O, R
Set O = CreateObject("Std.Registry")
Set R = CreateObject("Std.Arrays")
WScript.Echo R.ShowStructure( O.SearchTLIMethodsAndProperties( "MSSCRIPT.OCX",""))
```

Output from the demo (script was run in SciTE).

```
>cscript "C:\foo\foo.vbs"
{Add,AddCode,AddObject,AllowUI,Clear,CodeObject,Column,Count,Description,Error,Eval,ExecuteStatement,HasReturnValue,HelpContext,HelpFile,Item,Language,Line,Modules,Name,NumArgs,Number,Procedures,Reset,Run,SitehWnd,Source,State,Text,Timeout,UseSafeSubset}
>Exit code: 0
```

Finally, the VBA code. A cell has a symbol in it and this routine finds it or returns an error string.

```
Public Function LookupSymbol(sSym As String) As String
    Dim aRes As Variant
    aRes = reg.SearchTLIMethodsAndProperties("MSSCRIPT.OCX", sSym)
    Dim i As Integer
    LookupSymbol = "!!NotFound!!"
    For i = 0 To UBound(aRes)
    If LCase$(aRes(i)) = LCase$(sSym) Then
        LookupSymbol = sSym
        Exit For
    End If
    Next
End Function
```

Looking back on it now, I think I might pass in the path to the DLL/OCX as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Microsofts interactive OLE/COM-Object viewer to find mehods and their parameters in ActiveX-DLLs. Maybe looking at the source code of the viewer will lead you in the right direction: [MSDN OleView sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9yyfff5(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programmatically - I'm not aware of a *simple* way to do that. Anyway, if you really need to (and if your programming language is capable enough) - you can query the type library (refer to ITypeLib description somewhere at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221549.aspx).

Also, if you already have an IDispatch pointer - you might consider using its services to dynamically enumerate methods supported by the interface (refer to IDispatch description in MSDN).